# Angular alternative to double iteration

Tags: javascript, angular, iteration

I am working with two arrays of objects, and need data from both lists in order to correctly construct a "manufacturer list" dropdown, specifically a material mat-expansion-panel. Using javascript and Angular 7 in the frontend.

The first one is a master list of all manufacturers, like this: [{id: "56lkj456", label: "ABC Manufacturer"}]

There can be as many as 1200 of the above objects in that list. This list gets generated once upon initial app load.

The second list is a smaller list of manufacturers based on the user's search criteria, like this: [{id: "56lkj456", facets: 11}]

This list can have 200 or so items. This 2nd list is the one I'm interested in, but I need to get the manufacturer's name as well (which is in the first list).

Currently I am iterating through the master manufacturer list in the html file with a ul li *ngFor="let manufacturer of manufacturerList" ...

Was thinking I could have an *ngIf on the li that would call a function that would iterate through the 2nd list, and only display the manufacturer if the ids match up (i.e. if the manufacturers produced by the user search match the manufacturers in the master list).

Seems like a lot of computation to me, all for the sake of getting the name. Was wondering if anybody had any ideas to avoid this double iteration, other than changing the backend calls :-)

One idea I had was to make a dictionary out of the 1st list, where the ids are keys, and that way in my *ngIf I could cherry pick out a manufacturer from that dictionary, rather than iterate through.

Many thanks

Comment: Tip: to show some text as code in the question, apply the `{}` editor tool to it.

Comment: This is potentially a much larger question, but overall you should aim to process as much of the data ahead of time as possible. Structural directives such as *ngIf or similar usually will have negative affects on performance. Try to do as much as possible in `ngOnInit()` or prior to rendering.

Comment: Whatever you do on the front-end will be an overhead in comparison with adding the name to the initial array on the back-end

Comment: You can first sort the first list by id and then proceed with a dochotomic search

Comment: Build a map of the manufacturers. And build it while you're looping through it on initial load.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a dictionary, you can use a array find.

```
function findManufacturer(mID) {
    return manufacturerList.find(item => item.id === mID);
}
```

This will return the manufacturer object if the ID matches or undefined if the ID isn't found.

Comment: This is equivalent to iterate through the list

Comment: I agree, Baboo.  Is there anything that is more efficient in Angular - where it organizes them by ID and is smart enough to minimize the number of iterations?